# Why do we need pull-up resistors or tri state pins for AVR external interrupts?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmega, tri-state

Let's say we need to write a program for ATmega32, that reacts to an external interrupt(INT0) through the pin D2. The interrupt is to happen during the falling edge of the signal.

I noticed it in the books that
`DDRA = 0b00000010` is done to "activate the pull-up resistor". Why do we need it? Do we have to do the same if we want rising edge interrupt or a level triggered interrupt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Activating the pullup resistor is completely independent of detecting the signal. If the pin will be actively driven at all times then there is no need to activate the pullup, and in fact doing so will increase current consumption when the input is pulled low.

On the other hand, many external interrupt sources are actually [**open drain**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) outputs, which means that they are *not capable* of actively driving the input high. In this case we *must* activate the pullup resistor in order to prevent the input from floating.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another question, I don't have a strong background on electrical engineering. What happens, if we CLEAR DDRA.2 bit in that step, instead of SETting it, and that pin is as usual configured for interrupts?

Comment: `DDRx` controls the direction of a pin, not the activation of the internal pullup. See the datasheet for the AVR device, "I/O Ports" section, to see how `DDRx` and `PORTx` control pin behavior.